# How to have create-react version 2 above?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, package.json, react-scripts

I'm following one of the tutorial for reactjs. Now one of the topic is to check the version of my react-script in the package.json file. When I checked it's in version 0.9.5 but the instructor's copy is in 1.0+ now I want to upgrade my version my running `npm install react-script@latest` now it successfully updated to `2.0.5` but when I tried to create a new app using `create-react-app myproject` it's still using the `0.9.5` how can I install a new app with the latest version of react-scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the local version of create-react-app but then you're using the global one.

You should follow the official documentation about this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

The main points are:

1. Ensure you have npm > 5.2
2. If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.
3. `npx create-react-app my-app` (to create a new react app)